# xslt in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xslt

I know very little about ASP.NET, have to fix some broken layout in some ASP.NET webforms though. 
The following code:

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
...
<xml id="dataList_xsl">
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:extObject="urn:extObject">
<xsl:output method="html" />
<xsl:template match="/">
    <table unselectable="on" id="my_table_mains" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" class="dataListTable view" style="width: 100%;"> 
        <tr unselectable="on">
            COLUMNS_DEFINITION
        </tr>
...
```

should display NOTHING in the case of no match, and so it was in Internet Explorer 8,  however it displays the "COLUMNS_DEFINITION" in the newer versions of IE. 
How can I fix it?
I get a validation error on the  tag - Element 'xml' not supported, btw.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think it has anything to do with ASP.NET. IE (Internet Explorer) used to support an extension to HTML, so called *XML data islands*, where you put XML data or stylesheets into a new, proprietary element to HTML, the `xml` element. If you want to continue to use that element and have newer versions of IE support it then you need to make sure you set the `x-ua-compatible` to IE 8, either by sending the HTTP header or by including a `meta`:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8">
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx for details.

I wrote two test cases, with http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/html/test2013112001.html IE 10 on Windows 8 shows the content of the XSLT inside the `xml` element as the HTML 5 parser it has moves the `xml` stuff in the `head` section to the body (press F12 to see the parse tree) while with http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/html/test2013112002.html and the `meta` enforcement to use IE 8 the `xml` is recognized as an XML data island (press F12 to see parse tree) and does not output content inside of the XML data island.

Greg, if you still have problems then check that your ASP.NET is not sending a different HTTP `x-ua-compatible` header that might override the `meta`.

Here is a link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801224%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. It suggests a slightly different meta `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">`, in the end it amounts to ensure that the legacy parser is used that recognizes an `xml` element as an XML data island.

Comment: @Greg Martin is suggesting that you add that tag to your head element because it will cause IE 10 to behave like IE8 for that specific page.

Comment: @Greg, I posted links to two test cases showing that my suggestion with the `meta` should help. If you still have problems then maybe post a URL or check yourself whether your server perhaps sends a `x-ua-compatible` overriding the meta. Or at least use developer tools (F12) in IE 10 to tell use the browser mode and document mode.

Comment: Cheers, hopefully I can test it today.